# What are the repercussions if one turns down a green card acceptance?

Tags: usa, greencard

I read this [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157358/does-applying-for-the-diversity-green-card-lottery-affect-future-tourist-visits#comment392319_157358) from  [lalala](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/83250/lalala):

> Also dont forget the other case if you get accepted. There could be repercussions (for future visa/visits) if you turn down a Green Card acceptance.

What are the repercussions if one turns down a green card acceptance?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a not exactly on-target but related anecdotal experience.

A German friend entered the lottery several years ago, was accepted, and obtained a green card. A year or so later he changed his mind about emigration to the US and returned the card.

He's visited the US several times since as a tourist. On his first post-green card tourist trip, he endured a slightly-lengthened interview at the US border 'tho he was not taken to secondary. His subsequent entries to the US have been completely smooth and without issues.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience!